# Is a DB transaction executed when it is committed?

Tags: caching, database

`cache_get()` is not working as expected when called in a request initiated by `drupal_http_request()` on the same server.  Is it true that the `cache_set()` immediately before `drupal_http_request()` doesn't actually take place in the database until the first database transaction is committed?

Given the sequence:

- `cache_set($cid, $data)`
- `cache_get($cid)` // returns data
- external request using `drupal_http_request()`

  - `cache_get($cid)` // same $cid, returns FALSE
- `cache_get($cid)` // of course, returns data

To make the cached item available to the request initiated by `drupal_http_request()` I wrapped the cache_set call in a function like this, but it had no effect.

```
function cache_set_wrapper($cid, $data, $bin = 'cache', $expire = CACHE_PERMANENT) {
  $txn = db_transaction();
  return cache_set($cid, $data, $bin, $expire);
}
```

Why is there a discrepancy in the cache between the initial request on the second request?

Comment: That depends on where and how you are calling cache_set(). A transaction only exists if someone explicitly started it. If you're in a node, user or other entity insert/update hook for example, then yes, then you are in a transaction.

Comment: Very good.  This is from `hook_node_insert()`.  So my transaction is started after the one for the node.  Mine goes out of scope first, but does it get executed before the node_insert transaction is executed?

Comment: No, if there is an active transaction that it will only get committed at the end. Nested transactions are supported but only to rollback to a certain step. Does the external request need to happen immediately? Doing external requests from a entity crud hook is always a bit problematic for performance (imagine a bulk resave or import of nodes). Consider moving the http request to a shutdown function or a queue.

Comment: Thanks.  You've been incredibly helpful.  The external request doesn't need to happen immediately, so I'll see about using a queue.

Comment: Can you put your comments into an answer?  It's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, did that now. Didn't want to put something in an answer that was based on so much guessing, but worked out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from my comments:

That depends on where and how you are calling cache_set(). A transaction only exists if someone explicitly started it. If you're in a node, user or other entity insert/update hook for example, then yes, then you are in a transaction.

If there is an active transaction that it will only get committed at the end. Nested transactions are supported but only to rollback to a certain step. Does the external request need to happen immediately? Doing external requests from a entity crud hook is always a bit problematic for performance (imagine a bulk resave or import of nodes) too. Consider moving the HTTP request to a shutdown function or a queue.